# Why does `'aeee'.gsub(/(ae)*/, 'r')` result in `"rrerer"`?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have no idea how to explain the resut [sic] below:

```
'aeee'.gsub(/(ae)*/, 'r') # => "rrerer"
```

Answer (score 4):

You are getting that result because you are matching "ae" *zero* or more times.

The pointer is initially at the beginning of the string. "ae" is matched, and therefore will be replaced with "r". The pointer is now moved past the characters just matched ("ae"), before the second "e". Here the empty string is matched and replaced with "r". The pointer is now advanced past the second "e", before the third "e" and again an empty string is matched and replaced with "r". This happens once more after the pointer is moved past the the last "e".

You get the same result if it were in a non-capture group:

```
'aeee'.gsub(/(?:ae)*/, 'r') # => "rrerer"
```

Comment: You are missing the explanation for the final position (after "Same for the final 'e' ").

Comment: Thanks, @sawa. I fixed, and hopefully clarified, my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, try this:

```
'aeee'.gsub(/(ae)*/, 'r<\1>') # => "r<ae>r<>er<>er<>"
```

With `<\1>` you get also the catched expression and you see, the catch is an empty string.

Comment: I really like this technique. In fact, it showed me that the initial explanation I gave in my answer was muddled and incorrect (as flagged by @sawa). Here's an example of how the technique could be extended: `'aefg'.gsub(/(ae)*(?=(.?))/, 'r<\1,\2>') #=> 'r<ae,f>r<,f>fr<,g>gr<,>`. The positive lookahead `(?=(.?))` saves the character following the match (or `''` if there isn't one) in capture group 2.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your regex `(ae)*`, what are you doing ?

You are asking to match **zero** or **one** occurrence of `ae`.

- The first occurrence is *zero* or say nothing at beginning or string.
- Next it finds `ae`.
- Next it doesn't finds `ae` but since you are okay with it by using `*` that zero width is also matched.
- And so does the next one and the next one.

`|ae|e|e|` Here `|` denotes a match.

**[Regex101 Demo for better understanding.](https://regex101.com/r/mM4uV6/1)**

Comment: The first occurrence is not empty. The next match is not `ae`.

Comment: @sawa: What are you talking about sir ?